# What is the appropriate HTML markup for LinkedIn status updates?

Tags: html, social-media, structured-data, linkedin, open-graph-protocol

I am using [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) to power my website. I use [WordPress SEO by Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) as an SEO plugin of choice. It's a nice plugin, adds appropriate markup for Twitter, Facebook and Google Plus.

However, I noticed when posting company status updates on LinkedIn with links to a blog post of even just a page on our WordPress website, LinkedIn doesn't seem to pickup any thumbnails, title, or description.

Is there any special HTML markup required in order to help LinkedIn automatically know these things about my blog posts or pages when I post company status updates?

Comment: Do you use a security plugin, e.g., "Better WP Security"? Does your .htaccess contain a `HTTP_USER_AGENT` condition?

Comment: Yes, I use Better WP Security which is now iThemes Security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using *iThemes Security* (formerly *Better WP Security*), it may be the case that your .htaccess contains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Link [NC,OR]
```

This seems to block the LinkedIn bot from visiting your page (to get the metadata).

See the discussions:

- [WP Better Security LinkedIn Problem](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-better-security-linkedin-problem)
- [Better WP Security Blocks Open Graph Data](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/better-wp-security-blocks-open-graph-data)

And the bug report:

- [Hackrepair blocks LinkedIn](https://github.com/ithemes/iThemes-Security/issues/93)